# Name of Sci-Fi Book - Mercenaries Abducted by Aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel

In the late '70s or early '80s, I was looking at books at Tower Books - remember them?  There was a sci-fi novel about mercenaries in Southern Africa who were in a firefight. They were outnumbered and had to flee.  They ran into a craft which took off. Turned out to be piloted by aliens. The aliens either talked them or forced them to become mercenaries for them.  May have some of the facts wrong.

Drove me nuts over the years.  Would look for it at book stores but there are so many sci-fi novels.  Does anyone remember this?

Word of advice - if a book looks interesting, buy it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could be [Janissaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janissaries_(novel)) by Jerry Pournelle :

> In Janissaries, the leader is a United States Army officer from the Cold War period, Captain Rick Galloway, who along with his platoon-sized unit of soldiers primarily from the U.S. are abducted from a CIA-run operation against Cubans in the fictional tropical African country of Sainte-Marie by a flying saucer. The beings abducting them present themselves as rescuers from a hopeless situation where Galloway's unit is about to be overrun by Cubans in a night assault, the aftermath of which is expected to be the deaths of all. Afterwards, the human soldiers have the option of serving the aliens in a special situation involving a more primitive planet on which there are humans living in medieval conditions. The soldiers are expected to be able to use their superior weapons and tactics to conquer part of the planet.

Comment: Sure sounds like it.  I'll have to pick it up thanks. A lot less sleepless nights!